# Trig limit without using l'hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need help calculating this limit without L'Hopital's rule.

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(6x)-1}{x\sin(6x)}$$

Comment: I don't get this. This question clearly shows no effort, and other questions get closed for this reason, but this one gets upvotes and answers?

Comment: There should be a new flag for zero effort shown by OP in a text book type problem.

Answer (score 5):

**hint**: Use the followings facts:

$1)$ $\cos(6x) - 1 = -2\sin^2(3x)$,

$2)$ $\sin (6x) = 2\sin(3x)\cos(3x)$,

$3)$ $\sin(3x)/3x \to 1$ for $x \to 0$ of course.

$4)$ $\cos(3x) \to 1$.

Comment: How did we get to $3x$ in $\frac{sin3x}{3x}$?

Comment: simple: write $x = 3\left(\dfrac{x}{3}\right)$

Answer (score 1):

**The fast way:**

$$\cos(6x)-1=-2\sin^2(3x)\sim -18x^2,\\x\sin(6x)\sim6x^2$$

hence $-3$.

---

This is easily made rigourous by using a few $\dfrac{\sin t}t$ ratios.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $6(\cos(6x)+1)$, to get
$$
\frac{\cos^2(6x)-1}{6x\sin(6x)}\frac{6}{\cos(6x)+1}=
\frac{-\sin^2(6x)}{6x\sin(6x)}\frac{6}{\cos(6x)+1}=
-\frac{\sin(6x)}{6x}\frac{6}{\cos(6x)+1}
$$